# Spring Integration: Json transformer with snake case

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using Spring Integration + Spring Cloud Stream to create the following flow:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow testEventFlow(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from(TestEventSink.INPUT)
        .transform(Transformers.fromJson(TestEvent.class))
        .transform(TestEvent::getSomeId)
        .log()
        .channel("nullChannel")
        .get();
}
```

Test event class is:

```
public class TestEvent {

  private String someId;

  public TestEvent(){}

  public TestEvent(String someId){
      this.someId = someId;
  }

  public String getSomeId(){
      return someId;
  }

  public void setSomeId(String someId){
      this.someId = someId;
  }
}
```

Problem here is that messages from `TestEventSink.INPUT` are coming in snake case:

```
{ "some_id" : "1234" }
```

If I annotate Test Event class with `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)` it works well, but I can't annotate the class because it's from a third party library.

I tried to set the property `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE`, but It doesn't worked either.

I also tried:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
    return mapper;
}
```

But it doesn't worked.

I think that I can use a custom mapper for that transformation, but I'm looking for something that changes the configuration of all Spring Integration JSON transformers at same time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With `PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE` your ObjectMapper will work if you call it like this: `mapper.readValue(str, SomeClass.class);` . where str is the snake-cased-json-as-string and SomeClass is the POJO mapping to the JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the fact to inject auto-configured by Spring Boot `ObjectMapper` into the `fromJson()` factory:

```
. transform(Transformers.fromJson(TestEvent.class), 
       new Jackson2JsonObjectMapper(objectMapper))
```

The point is that Spring Integration comes before Spring Boot, but not vice versa, therefore the auto-configuration is not visible in Spring Integration as is.

Comment: Ok, so the only way is a custom mapper in every transformer call